# Custom Shortcode, functions PHP WP_Query loop

Tags: functions, loop, shortcode

I have the following code in my functions.php file:-

```
function featured_properties_func( $atts ) {

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_type'     => 'properties',

    );
    $featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $featured_query->have_posts() ):

            while( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post();

                $featured_properties = get_the_title();

                return $featured_properties;

            endwhile;

        endif; wp_reset_query();

    }
add_shortcode( 'featured_properties', 'featured_properties_func' );
```

When I output the shortcode I'm only getting one value where as it should be returning 6.

What I want to do is loop all the properties and return the title of each, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning inside your loop - so it returns on the first iteration, giving you one result only.

You should build a string inside your loop instead, and only return when the loop is over.

Something like

```
$featured_properties = '';

      if( $featured_query->have_posts() ):

            while( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post();

                $featured_properties .= get_the_title() . '<br />';

            endwhile;

        endif; wp_reset_query();

 return $featured_properties;
```